# What's the reason for letting the semantics of a=a++ be undefined?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, language-lawyer

The line

```
a = a++;
```

is undefined behaviour in C. The question I am asking is: **why?**

I mean, I get that it might be hard to provide a consistent order in which things should be done. But, certain compilers will always do it in one order or the other (at a given optimization level). So why exactly is this left up to the compiler to decide?

To be clear, I want to know if this was a design decision and if so, what prompted it? Or maybe there is a hardware limitation of some kind?

Comment: Good question. Java took a different approach here. (Well, they did so for every situation which C/C++ triggers UB, since no Java program have UB :-)

Comment: “But, certain compilers will always do it in one order or the other.” This is not quite true. Some compilers do it one way at one optimization level and the other way at another optimization level.

Comment: Well, I tested on Mono on Ubuntu and it works fine. Looks like C thing. But can you explain why you need write something like this? because the `++` operator do already the work of `=` operator...

Comment: @PascalCuoq : I wasn't aware of that, thianks. I'll update the question text

Comment: @Jack : I will never ever write this in any production code. I am simply in the process of reading through "deepC" and came across this snippet which was undefined behaviour. Suprisingly, I couldn't find any good answer as to why it was undefined.

Comment: It basically boils down to "So the compiler doesn't have to think too hard about how to implement `a=b++`." (and it may well find itself in situations where it can't actually prove that a and b aren't the same, and the way that "works" when they are the same may actually be slower than others that work when they're not.)

Comment: Recommended reading: [What Wvery C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

Comment: Related: [Some exam questions *rely* on undefined behaviour](https://www.quora.com/Why-should-I-use-GCC-and-Clang-over-Turbo-C/answer/Greg-Kemnitz) (actually defined behaviour for a particular compiler ([Turbo C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B))) (Kanetkar's books)

Comment: Don't some compilers issue a warning?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

UPDATE: This question was [the subject of my blog on June 18th, 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/06/18/implementation-defined-behaviour.aspx). Thanks for the great question!

---

> Why? I want to know if this was a design decision and if so, what prompted it?

You are essentially asking for the minutes of the meeting of the ANSI C design committee, and I don't have those handy. If your question can only be answered definitively by someone who was in the room that day, then you're going to have to find someone who was in that room.

However, I can answer a broader question:

> What are some of the factors that lead a language design committee to leave the behaviour of a legal program (`*`) "undefined" or "implementation defined" (`**`)?

The first major factor is: **are there two existing implementations of the language in the marketplace that disagree on the behaviour of a particular program?** If FooCorp's compiler compiles `M(A(), B())` as "call A, call B, call M", and BarCorp's compiler compiles it as "call B, call A, call M", and neither is the "obviously correct" behaviour then there is strong incentive to the language design committee to say "you're both right", and make it implementation defined behaviour. *Particularly this is the case if FooCorp and BarCorp both have representatives on the committee.*

The next major factor is: **does the feature naturally present many different possibilities for implementation?** For example, in C# the compiler's analysis of a "query comprehension" expression is specified as "do a syntactic transformation into an equivalent program that does not have query comprehensions, and then analyze that program normally". There is very little freedom for an implementation to do otherwise.

By contrast, the C# specification says that the `foreach` loop should be treated as the equivalent `while` loop inside a `try` block, but allows the implementation some flexibility. A C# compiler is permitted to say, for example "I know how to implement `foreach` loop semantics more efficiently over an array" and use the array's indexing feature rather than converting the array to a sequence as the specification suggests it should.

A third factor is: **is the feature so complex that a detailed breakdown of its exact behaviour would be difficult or expensive to specify?** The C# specification says very little indeed about how anonymous methods, lambda expressions, expression trees, dynamic calls, iterator blocks and async blocks are to be implemented; it merely describes the desired semantics and some restrictions on behaviour, and leaves the rest up to the implementation.

A fourth factor is: **does the feature impose a high burden on the compiler to analyze?** For example, in C# if you have:

```
Func<int, int> f1 = (int x)=>x + 1;
Func<int, int> f2 = (int x)=>x + 1;
bool b = object.ReferenceEquals(f1, f2);
```

Suppose we require b to be true. *How are you going to determine when two functions are "the same"*?  Doing an "intensionality" analysis -- do the function bodies have the same content? -- is hard, and doing an "extensionality" analysis -- do the functions have the same results when given the same inputs? -- is even harder. A language specification committee should seek to minimize the number of open research problems that an implementation team has to solve!

In C# this is therefore left to be implementation-defined; a compiler can choose to make them reference equal or not at its discretion.

A fifth factor is: **does the feature impose a high burden on the runtime environment?**

For example, in C# dereferencing past the end of an array is well-defined; it produces an array-index-was-out-of-bounds exception. This feature can be implemented with a small -- not zero, but small -- cost at runtime.  Calling an instance or virtual method with a null receiver is defined as producing a null-was-dereferenced exception; again, this can be implemented with a small, but non-zero cost. The benefit of eliminating the undefined behaviour pays for the small runtime cost.

A sixth factor is: **does making the behaviour defined preclude some major optimization**?  For example, C# defines the ordering of side effects *when observed from the thread that causes the side effects*. But the behaviour of a program that observes side effects of one thread from another thread is implementation-defined except for a few "special" side effects. (Like a volatile write, or entering a lock.)  If the C# language required that all threads observe the same side effects in the same order then we would have to restrict modern processors from doing their jobs efficiently; modern processors depend on out-of-order execution and sophisticated caching strategies to obtain their high level of performance.

Those are just a few factors that come to mind; there are of course many, many other factors that language design committees debate before making a feature "implementation defined" or "undefined".

Now let's return to your specific example.

The C# language *does* make that behaviour strictly defined(`†`); the side effect of the increment is observed to happen before the side effect of the assignment. So there cannot be any "well, it's just impossible" argument there, because it is possible to choose a behaviour and stick to it. Nor does this preclude major opportunities for optimizations. And there are not a multiplicity of possible complex implementation strategies.

My *guess*, therefore, and I emphasize that this is a *guess*, is that the C language committee made ordering of side effects into implementation defined behaviour because there were multiple compilers in the marketplace that did it differently, none was clearly "more correct", and the committee was unwilling to tell half of them that they were wrong.

---

(`*`) Or, sometimes, its compiler! But let's ignore that factor.

(`**`) "Undefined" behaviour means that the code can do *anything*, including erasing your hard disk. The compiler is not required to generate code that has any particular behaviour, and not required to tell you that it is generating code with undefined behaviour. "Implementation defined" behaviour means that the compiler author is given considerable freedom in choice of implementation strategy, but is required to *pick a strategy*, *use it consistently*, and *document that choice*.

(`†`) When observed from a single thread, of course.

Comment: Since this question was tagged C rather than C#, it would be a lot nicer if you had used examples from C...

Comment: @R..: I have only been on the language design teams or standarization committees for C#, Visual Basic, VBScript, ECMAScript, JScript and JScript.NET; I have never been on the language standardization committee for C so I did not feel it was appropriate that I give examples. If you feel that it would be appropriate to do so, then I invite you to write your own answer that you like better that gives examples from the C standardization committee.

Comment: There are a lot of possible things a compiler could sensibly do with `a=a++;` that would have weird and undesired effects, but nearly all could be characterized as "Decide by some possibly-unpredictable means to either cause `a` to get loaded with some possibly-unpredictable value,. or trigger some kind of trap, whose consequences, depending upon the underlying platform, may or may not be predictable."  The authors of the standard probably didn't think anyone would benefit from having things defined in that way (versus simply "undefined"), but in fact it would have made a huge difference.

Comment: There are a lot of cases, such as when decoding a file that may or pay not contain valid graphics or audio data, where it would be acceptable to have nonsense data yield a wide range of behaviors, but having it trigger modern-style Undefined Behavior would not be acceptable.  I'd be curious to know your take on modern compilers' use of behavior which isn't defined by the C standard (but may have been defined on many platforms) as an excuse to negate the laws of time and causality.

Answer (score 12):

It's undefined because there is no good reason for writing code like that, and by not requiring any specific behaviour for bogus code, compilers can more aggressively optimize well-written code. For example, `*p = i++` may be optimized in a way that causes a crash if `p` happens to point to `i`, possibly because two cores write to the same memory location at the same time. The fact that this also happens to be undefined in the specific case that `*p` is explicitly written out as `i`, to get `i = i++`, logically follows.

Comment: Could you please explain what `possibly because two cores write to the same memory location at the same time` mean? Are you talking about parallel computing?

Comment: @ajay Sort of, but not exactly. If `*p = i++` is compiled to (pseudo-assembly) `mov r1, (&i); mov r2, (&p); inc (&i); mov (r2), r1;` it's conceivable that the execution of `inc (&i);` is not yet finished once the execution of `mov (r2), r1;` starts. For the most common processors, this isn't an issue, but there are some odd ones out there.

Answer (score 7):

With a few exceptions, the order in which expressions are evaluated is unspecified; this was a deliberate design decision, and it allows implementations to rearrange the evaluation order from what's written if that will result in more efficient machine code.  Similarly, the order in which the side effects of `++` and `--` are applied is unspecified beyond the requirement that it happen before the next sequence point, again to give implementations the freedom to arrange operations in an optimal manner.

Unfortunately, this means that the result of an expression like `a = a++` will vary based on the compiler, compiler settings, surrounding code, etc.  The behavior is specifically called out as undefined in the language standard so that compiler implementors don't have to worry about detecting such cases and issuing a diagnostic against them.  Cases like `a = a++` are obvious, but what about something like

```
void foo(int *a, int *b)
{
  *a = (*b)++;
}
```

If that's the only function in the file (or if its caller is in a different file), there's no way to know at compile time whether `a` and `b` point to the same object; what do you do?

Note that it's entirely possible to mandate that all expressions be evaluated in a specific order, and that all side effects be applied at a specific point in evaluation; that's what Java and C# do, and in those languages expressions like `a = a++` are always well-defined.

Comment: One could also specify that a compiler is allowed to perform the various steps of the operation in any order that it desires, yielding whatever result that happens to yield, or trap code which happens to use illegitimately-aliased values, without implying that compilers should infer that any condition which would have be true to prevent an illegitimately-aliased access occurring may be assumed to be true without having to actually check it.  Indeterminate Value rules could leave a lot of room for optimization without negating the laws of causality.

Answer (score 6):

It's ambiguous but not syntactically wrong. What should `a` be? Both `=` and `++` have the same "timing." So instead of defining an arbitrary order it was left undefined since either order would be in conflict with  one of the two operators definitions.

Comment: But do they have the same timing though? I mean one could argue that since the code is read from left to right, then the left side of the `=` operator should be evaluated first and then the right side. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: How you read the code and how the operators are defined are separate. According to the language, I am pretty sure they have the same timing.  Even in your example, how can I evaluate `=` without evaluating `++` which by definition must happen last which would then destroy the `=` operation.

Answer (score 3):

The postfix `++` operator returns the value prior to the incrementation. So, at the first step, `a` gets assigned to its old value (that's what `++` returns). At the next point it is undefined whether the increment or the assignment will take place first, because both operations are applied over the same object (`a`), and the language says nothing about the order of evaluation of these operators.

Comment: I think the question is _why_ it's unspecified: why not simple choose to specify that one or the other happens first?

Comment: If it were unspecified, you could rely on having the increment happen first and then the assignment, or having the assignment happen first and then the increment. In other words, if it were unspecified, there would be no more than two valid results. It's not unspecified. It's undefined. *Any* behaviour is valid, and you may in practise see different behaviour from the two possibilities you suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Somebody may provide another reason, but from an optimization (better say assembler presentation) point of view, `a` needs be loaded into a CPU register, and the postfix operator's value should be placed into another register or the same.

So the last assignment can depend on either the optimizer using one register or two.

Comment: I don't think you can/should optimize an undefined behavior

Comment: @Andrew White - :) I'm not going, but standard of C doesn't declares how code mapped to assembly instruction. But if you mentally try to do this you could see lot of side effects that appears.

Comment: @AndrewWhite: Historically, saying that something was "undefined behavior" meant that the standard did not impose any requirements, but compilers were free to (and often did) assign useful behaviors as they saw fit.  For example, if `x` and `y` are unrelated pointers, the Standard not only allows `x<y` to yield an arbitrary value--it would allow that expression to do *anything whatsoever*, but until recently compilers for systems with linear address spaces would almost always implement a transitive comparison relation where addresses within distinct objects won't overlap.  On some platforms...

Comment: ...implementing such a relation would be very expensive, and the fastest method of comparison which would work on pointers to the same object might trap or behave strangely when given pointers to different objects; the authors of the Standard didn't want to require such platforms to use the slower comparisons, but platforms which could perform such comparisons at the same speed as any other have traditionally done so.  Nonetheless, some hyper-modern compilers take the view that no chain of events which would cause unrelated pointers to be used with the `<` operator can possibly occur...

Comment: ...and will thus decide the best way to optimize the program is to omit any part of the code which would only be relevant under such circumstances, completely undermining the usefulness of many kinds of security checks.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the same object twice without an intervening sequence point is undefined behaviour ...

- because that makes compiler writers happier
- because it allows implementations to define it anyway
- because it doesn't force a specific constraint when it isn't needed

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `a` is a pointer with value *0x0001FFFF*. And suppose the architecture is segmented so that the compiler needs to apply the increment to the high and low parts separately, with a carry between them. The optimiser could conceivably reorder the writes so that the final value stored is *0x0002FFFF*; that is, the low part before the increment and the high part after the increment.

This value is twice either value that you might have expected. It may point to memory not owned by the application, or it may (in general) be a trapping representation. In other words, the CPU may raise a hardware fault as soon as this value is loaded into a register, crashing the application. Even if it doesn't cause an immediate crash, it is a profoundly wrong value for the application to be using.

The same kind of thing can happen with other basic types, and the C language allows even ints to have trapping representations. C tries to allow efficient implementation on a wide range of hardware. Getting efficient code on a segmented machine such as the 8086 is hard. By making this undefined behaviour, a language implementer has a bit more freedom to optimise aggressively. I don't know if it has ever made a performance difference in practice, but evidently the language committee wanted to give every benefit to the optimiser.

Comment: Suppose the C standard had said: "If multiple read/write operations to a variable occur other than as described here, an an implementation any arbitrarily decide to have reads yield arbitrary values and writes store arbitrary values, or trigger a trap whose *existence* must be implementation-defined but whose effects need not be".  Such a rule would have been synonymous with saying action invokes Undefined Behavior under the understanding of the term that existed prior to roughly 2010.  In practice, if a programmer knows code isn't going to be run on a platform where traps would have...

Comment: ...unacceptable consequences, specifying the former definition would allow some code to be written in more efficient fashion while meeting requirements than would be possible if code had to avoid all Undefined Behavior.  Even more such improvements would be possible if the rule provided that repeated stores of the same value would be harmless.  Unfortunately, some compiler writers think it's better to "optimize" code by allowing weird and wacky behaviors in such cases than to allow programmers to make use of minimally-specified behaviors.