# Warning about undefined increment on int

Tags: c, avr-gcc

I'm having a weird problem with avr-gcc. If I do this:

```
int i = 0;
i = ++i;
```

It results in the compiler warning:

```
warning: operation on ‘i’ may be undefined
```

What is wrong here?

If it is rewritten to

```
i = i + 1;
```

It does not result in the warning.

avr-gcc is version 4.3.4 and I'm running this on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: I'd like to know why you think this is a weird problem.  What is your reason for writing code like that in the first place?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point Also, you don't assign initial value to i.

Comment: It's a simplification of a different piece of code. The original line is: pos = ++pos & 0xf; However the problem is only refering to the prefix operator.

Comment: My bad. Same result if variable is initialized.

Comment: eleweek gave the hint. The operator `&`introduces a sequence point, therefore crashes your "simplification" the term.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the reason for letting the semantics of a=a++ be undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943697/whats-the-reason-for-letting-the-semantics-of-a-a-be-undefined)

Comment: `&` does not introduce a sequence point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you intended to simply increment `i`, then use *either*

```
i = i + 1;
```

or

```
++i;
```

(or `i++`), but not both. The rules of C don't permit you to modify a variable twice before a single sequence point. Both the preincrement (`++i`) and the assignment (`i =`) modify the value of `i`.

Comment: This! Also one should mention: "undefined behaviour". This is exactly what the compiler tells us.

Comment: So I get this warning because ++i operates directly on the variable, whereas i+1 operates on an intermediate, right?

Comment: @Kenneth: You get the warning because *both* `++i` and `i =` attempt to modify the value of `i`. The compiler is free to generate code that does this in any order, so the value that ends up in `i` is undefined. (Note that the preincrement operator only says that the value is incremented before being used in the expression, not that the incremented value is *stored* back into `i` before it is used).