# How to extract more value from one variable

Tags: c, pic

from the result in my "for" loop, have stored four value.
How to extract that value to show the value(sprintf) ?

Kindly refer to the attached the image file.

[image: Extrac value in ADC1BUF0]

Here the code :

```
for( a = 4; a < 5; a = a++ )
           {
                 AD1CHS0bits.CH0SA = a   ;  //select which ANI connect to channel 0
                 AD1CHS0bits.CH0NA = 0   ;  //vref as channel 0 -ve input
                 AD1CON1bits.ADON  = 1   ;
                 AD1CON1bits.SAMP = 1    ;
                 __delay32(50)           ;
                 AD1CON1bits.SAMP = 0    ;   //sampling bit to 0
                 while(!AD1CON1bits.DONE);
                 result = ADC1BUF0       ;
           }
```

Here my sprinf code:

```
           sprintf(lala,"test: %d, %d, %d, %d\r\n",result);
           sendString(lala);
           __delay32(20000);
```

Thanks

Regards, 
Nazif

Comment: Are you serious about this :  `a = 4; a < 5; a = a++` ? You probably want this: `a = 4; a < 5; a++`, but this is still doubtful, your loop will run only once.

Comment: What type is `result`?

Comment: note: writing a=a++ in your loop will cause infinite loop because, the a++ will increment the value in a but only after the assignment so a will remain the same. Instead you should write (a = 4;a < 5; a++)

Comment: I should probably use 'a = 4; a < 5; a++'
thanks for the correction

Comment: @NazifJaafar your `sprintf` resulta in undefibed behaviour, you have 4 `%d` format specifiers but you provide only one argument (`result`).

Comment: The type of the result is in numbers, before run the for loop I declared (int result =  0)

Comment: @NazifJaafar so you want simply print the content of the `result` variable ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz, yup, you are right. But I not sure what variable to put. I got error if I put (result0,result1,result2,result3)

Comment: @MichaelWalz, Actually I thought if I put (result), it will print four value. Sorry I am new to C programming.

Comment: @NazifJaafar I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you want `sprintf(lala,"test: %d\r\n",result);`. Please tell us what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you want to print every byte of `result` seperately? If yes, `uint32_t` might be a better choice since an `int` is only required to be able to hold the value `2^16 - 1`. Show us how `ADC1BUF0` is created, please.

Comment: @cad, I got an error if I use (uint32_t) . Kindly refer this image.http://i.imgur.com/cM4G9Z5.png
 It show my result if I use (sprintf(lala,"test: %d\r\n",result))

Comment: @cad, when a =0 , ADC1BUF0 will read the value from port1 in my circuit, when a = 1,ADC1BUF0  will read from others port, until port 4. so , it can show four result.

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies: actually, `a=a++` is undefined behaviour. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943697/whats-the-reason-for-letting-the-semantics-of-a-a-be-undefined

Comment: @KarolyHorvath didn't know that, thanks. I executed that loop and it turned out to be infinite, as I guessed, so I thought a = a++ does as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you basically have:

```
for( a = 4; a < 5; a = a++ )
{
   /* code to sample one channel and store
    * the result in "result" */
}
```

...which you expect to sample each of four channels, then you try to print all four results with:

```
sprintf(lala,"test: %d, %d, %d, %d\r\n",result);
sendString(lala);
__delay32(20000);
```

First, your loop currently only does one iteration (after correcting `a = a++` to `a++`), with `a` equal to `4`.  You appear to need it to loop from 0 to 3 (for AN0-AN3):

```
for ( a = 0; a < 4; a++ )
```

Also, `result` will only hold one value at a time.  Each time through the loop, the assignment replaces the old `result` value with the new one -- it doesn't add a second, third, etc. value to `result` but rather it changes the one value `result` holds.  So you need to either have four separate variables (such as 4 elements of an array), or to do what you need to with each value in the loop so that you're finished with it before you read the next one.  With an array, you might have:

```
int results[4];

/* ... */

for( a = 0; a < 4; a++ )
{
    /* ... */
    results[a] = ADC1BUF0;
}

/* ... */

sprintf(lala,"test: %d, %d, %d, %d\r\n",
        results[0],results[1],results[2],results[3]);
sendString(lala);
__delay32(20000);
```